# Is Br sp³-hybridised in HBr?

Tags: hybridization

$\ce{HBr}$ formation can be explained by simple orbital overlap as well as by $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridisation of $\ce{Br}.$ Can't we use dipole moment to find if the lone pairs on $\ce{Br}$ are mutually perpendicular or $\mathrm{sp^3}$-hybridised?

Comment: Hybridization is a convenient rule, but more modern molecular orbital theory does not use it.  For HF see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwikzubA4JjkAhUMOK0KHfO3B8kQjB16BAgBEAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchem.libretexts.org%2FBookshelves%2FPhysical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps%2FSupplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)%2FChemical_Bonding%2FMolecular_Orbital_Theory%2FMO_for_HF&psig=AOvVaw2y26sctg_Z36k11rINHt_m&ust=1566641490289608), for example.

Comment: I don't understand how the dipole moment will help at all. The molecule has $C_{\infty}$ symmetry. There is only one direction the dipole moment, if it exists, can point.

Comment: If you add the three lone pairs when they would be in sp³-hybrid orbitals, it would be just the same as if they were in s and p orbitals. Hybridisation is just a mathematical trick. If we are employing any of this theory (and including molecular orbital theory), then the orbitals are always chosen orthogonal to each other. A note on language: Atoms *cannot* be hybridised, only orbitals can. Therefore it is incorrect (or at least very sloppy) to speak of sp³ hybridisation of bromine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a theoretical viewpoint we would expect the Br to be sp3 hybridized, because in the HBr molecule the Br atom has 4 pairs of electrons around it (the 3 lone pairs plus the bonding pair), and symmetry (plus the repulsion of electrons for each other) tells us to expect that 4 pairs of electrons arrange themselves in a tetrahedron, and as you know we explain a tetrahedral arrangement of electron pairs around an atom by arguing the s and p atomic orbitals form sp3 hybrid orbitals.

It's the same valence shell electron pair repulsion (VSEPR) logic that leads us  to expect the 4 bonding pairs around the C in CH4 should be arranged tetrahedrally, and, therefore, the C atom is sp3 hybridized.  (We would also expect that a more careful and precise determination would give us some deviation from this prediction for HBr, since unlike CH4 the 4 electron pairs around the Br in HBr are not equivalent.)

But you are interested in the question of whether there could be some experimental verification of this expectation.  I don't think the experimental dipole moment would work, because it's too crude a picture of the electron distribution, it just tells us whether the electrons spend extra time near the H or near the Br, and we already know it will be the Br because of its much stronger effective nuclear charge for valence electrons.  What you want to know is something like whether the valence electrons spend significantly extra time on the "far" side of the Br, away from the H-Br bond, as opposed to the "near" side, so we can conclude they're in sp3 hybrid orbitals that point away from the H-Br bond.  Offhand I can't think of an experiment that would unambiguously test this.

You could certainly *calculate* the electron density in the HBr molecule, with a good quantum chemistry package, and for a molecule this small the results should be quite reliable.  That would tell you whether it makes more sense to consider the Br lone pairs as in sp3 hybrid orbitals or atomic p orbitals.